# Sublists in Distribution Lists using DirectoryServices

Tags: vb.net, directoryservices, distribution-list

This is a win form I am building from .Net and I need to get the members of each security group.  Some of our security groups have subgroups and I need the program to be able to distinguish that and run through the members of a sub group.

Here is my code:

```
Dim thisDL As String = cmbADGroups.GetItemText(cmbADGroups.SelectedItem)
Dim dn As String = "CN=" & thisDL & ",OU=DistributionLists,DC=ThisDC,DC=com"
Dim ctx As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
Dim group As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, 3, dn)
Dim members As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = group.GetMembers()
Dim PersonList = (From m In members
                  Order By m.DisplayName
                  Select New OaklawnPerson With {.userFullName = m.DisplayName,
                                                 .userID = m.SamAccountName,
                                                 .userEmail = m.UserPrincipalName,
                                                 .userFirstName = m.DisplayName.Split(",").Last()}).ToList
dgvSearchResults.DataSource = OaklawnPersonList
```

My question:
This works when there are not any sub-distribution lists under, however when there is one or more sublists, I need to identify that it is indeed a sublist and get members from it (and even if there is a sub of a sub).
I am not asking for anyone to write code for me, but maybe point me in the direction I need to go.
Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results will be of type `Principal`, but if it's a group you will see that it's a `GroupPrincipal`. I'm primarily a C# developer, but it would be something like:

```
If TypeOf m Is GroupPrincipal Then ...
```

then you can treat it as a group. I'm not sure you can pull that off in a Linq query, so you might be better off changing that to a `For Each` loop.

I have some example code to do this directly with `DirectoryEntry` (which is what `GroupPrincipal`, etc. uses behind the scenes anyway), which I find is much faster. But I did it in C#. It can of course be translated to VB.NET: [Find all the members of a group](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html#systemdirectoryservices)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link as it does help for sure.  I actually changed it to a for each Principal in GroupPrincipal and doing an if on StructuralObjectClass (either "user" or "group") however I probably could convert that to TypeOf.  And my next conundrum is if there is a sub of a sub.  I don't even know the deepest part of our AD structure.

Comment: You could use recursion. So if your method is called `GetGroupMembers`, then when it comes across a group, just call `GetGroupMembers` again and add the members it returns to the list you have going.

Comment: Thanks.  That is exactly what I will be doing.